# Extract all text from specific <ul> within a parent container with multiple dynamic child using puppeteer and cheerio

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I want to extract the texts from `<ul>` elements using puppeteer and cheerio. My problem is that there is no classes on `<ul>` elements and the count of `<ul>` element varies each time based on search, so I could not use `nth-child`. I have tried every possible way as far as I know, but couldn't get the desired results. Is there any way around. I have this structure and classes only available with the parent element:

```
<div class="card-section">
    <div class="right text--pull">
      <h6>Description:</h6>
      <p>Some text</p>

      <h6>Features</h6>
        <ul>
            <li>lines</li>
            <li>lines</li>  
            ....      
        </ul>

        <h6>Includes</h6>
        <ul>
            <li>lines</li>
            <li>lines</li>
            ....
        </ul>

        <h6>Titles:</h6>
        <ul>
            <li>lines</li>
            <li>lines</li>
            ....
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is what I have tried so far:
in the helper.js.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            timeout: 0,
            headless: false,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            ignoreHTTPErrors: true,
            args: ["--start-maximized", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
            ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--disable-extensions", "--enable-automation"],
            slowMo: 200,
          });
let skus='sdfh65asdchv'
let arr = await scrapeUl(page, skus);
            await sleep(3000);
            
            await page.close();
```

In scrapeUl I have:

```
const scrapeUl = async (page, singleSku) => {
  await page.goto("https://myweb.com", { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
  await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="parent-container-id"]/section/header/div/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div/div');
  let [Input] = await page.$x('//*[@id="parent-container-id"]/section/header/div/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div/div/input');
  await Input.type(singleSku);
  let [SearchBtn] = await page.$x('//*[@id="parent-container-id"]/section/header/div/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div/button');
  await Promise.all([
      page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}),
      page.keyboard.press("Enter"),
    ]);

    /* I want to scrape specification part of <ul> which can be any of the <ul> element, and it dynamically changes 
        Sometimes it scrape but sometimes it skips since number of child changes in the parent container
        as one can see there are no classes or ids attached to <ul> element, this makes harder for me to select this element
    */
    const specifications = await page.$eval('div.card__section > div > ul:nth-child(8)', (el) => el.innerText);


  };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I have tried every possible way as far as I know, but couldn't get the desired results. Is there any way around[?]"_

you should name (include the code of) the approaches you've already tried, otherwise, how will others know that the solution they suggest isn't something you've already tried?

Comment: Puppeteer and cheerio work on totally different use cases. I don't see code from either library here, but it's unclear whether this is static HTML or a dynamic JS-powered site, or any context for parent containers or JS behavior. For example, if this is nested in an iframe, then Puppeteer won't be able to get at it without extra work. So please provide the site and a [mcve] with your code so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

-- a section of your HTML--

```
   <ul id="demo">
        <li>lines</li>
         <li>lines</li>  
         ....      
    </ul>
```

--In JavaScript---

```
 <script>
    alert(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML);
 </script>
```

You can add an "id" to the `<ul>` you want to pull, add a script function that returns `document.getElementById("<ID NAME>").innerHTML`

Here, innerHTML pulls the string of the `<ul>` not the object itself. you can assign a variable (maybe in this case an array) to store the strings of the `<ul>` to manipulate further. Here I have it just displaying it as an alert so you can see what it returns. In this case- it returns "lines, lines ...." in the alert.

Comment: Thanks @harp, but this html is dynamic and rendered by different server. Sorry for not clarifying. I have updated my question. Thanks